# How to switch Synthesized Speech voice when reading from a file using SAY command

Tags: macos

I'm using the say command on macOSX to read from a file that has text in two different languages. Is it possible to indicate in the file from where it reads the content when to use a different voice?

```
say -v Samantha -f speach.txt
```

The content of speach.txt

```
Thank you for calling XYZ.[[slnc 300]] 
Para español, marque 2.[[slnc 300]]
```

Comment: The `say` _command_  is not going to speak the `[[slnc 300]]` portion of the line in that text, and changing the voice isn't going to properly pronounce what's in Spanish on a system set to English as its primary language. After reviewing the manual page for the `say` _command_, I do not see a way to have different portions of the file read in different voices, as is. If you need to keep it all in one file, then you could do it in AppleScript, either in Script Editor or using `osascript` in Terminal.

Comment: the [[slnc 300]] portion is there indicating a silence.and its working.  the -v command is to indicate the voice (and language) that will be used regardless of the primary language of the system.

Comment: Sorry I missed in the manual page what the `[[slnc 300]]` does, but that doesn't change what else I said! Especially about proper pronunciation, no matter what voice you use, if English is the primary language `Para español, marque 2` is not going to be properly pronounced because it's being spoken in English not Spanish. Anyway, if you what an example of how to do it as a AppleScript, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Found this today (5 years after the post)

Not sure when the other language voices were introduced, but Paulina will translate to spanish, at least `2` is translated as `dos`

```
say -v Paulina "Para español, marque 2"
```